# How to set a value to a cell from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop that return a value of a string, and i want to place the outcomes of it to a cell.
but when I running the loop and it return it value, I get the error msg type mismatch.

```
Sub Get_IMM_4_1()

Dim Cells(30, 30) As String

test = GetDataOfMonth("IMM_4_1", "Alarm 1 EMS")
Worksheets(MonthView).Cells(30, 30) = test

End Sub


Function GetDataOfMonth(Optional IMM, Optional Alarm) As String


counter = 0

    For sheet = 1 To 31
        For Row = 2 To 150
                If Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Row, 1).Value = IMM And Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Row, 4).Value = Alarm Then
                  counter = counter + 1
                End If
                If Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Row, 1).Value = IMM And Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Row, 4).Value = Alarm Then
                  counter = counter + 1
                End If
                If Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Row, 1).Value = IMM And Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Row, 4).Value = Alarm Then
                  counter = counter + 1
                End If
        Next Row
    Next sheet


GetDataOfMonth = counter

Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Exactly which line cause the error?

Comment: `MonthView` is worksheet name or a variable? You do not need to define this variable `Dim Cells(30, 30) As String`

Comment: Sub Get_IMM_4_1()

Dim Cells(30, 30) As String

test = GetDataOfMonth("IMM_4_1", "Alarm 1 EMS")
Worksheets(MonthView).Cells(30, 30) = test

End Sub

I have now changed it with

Sub Get_IMM_4_1()

Worksheets("MonthView").Cells(30, 30) = GetDataOfMonth("IMM_4_1", "Alarm 1 EMS")
 

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

If `MonthView` is sheet name then you have to wrap it with double quotation to qualify as string. Otherwise excel will treat it as a variable and will cause error as no variable defined with this name. Try like below.

```
Worksheets("MonthView").Cells(30, 30) = test
```

Comment: Tank you so much, it works fine.
You are my hero!! ;P

Comment: If you found it helpful then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it).